# Ember Js How to create dynamic nested Routes

Tags: javascript, ember.js

It is possible to create routes with dynamic hierarchies?

I need to define a route to a modal, and preserve the view of the previous route, and this modal can be accessed from the application of the index or any other route.

example:

/ modal 
Maintains the view of the home and displays the modal.

/ sub-page / modal 
Keeps view of sub-page and displays the modal

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of how to display modal dialogs in the Ember cookbooks: http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/

The technique involves creating a separate `outlet` for your modal.  You can put this in your application template and control its position in the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Steve, but I need open this mobal by a router.